# There is a issue with lazy-loading. I am having some problem with child routing

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, parent-child

This is my app-routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'user',loadChildren:()=>import('./user/user.module').then(m=>m.UserModule),canActivate:[AuthGuardService]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my userModule

Problem is that I want **AskQuestionComponent** http://localhost:4200/user/ask-question
but **AskQuestionComponent** is also rendering on http://localhost:4200/ask-question
I dont understand why.
And same is the case with **UserAnswersComponent**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: UserHomeComponent},
  {path:'ask-question',component:AskQuestionComponent},
  {path:'answers',component:UserAnswersComponent}
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue but this seems to work as expected, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-75rrhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html . The 1st 2 links work while the last 2 throws error as expected

Comment: @OwenKelvinBut I am not getting error on http://localhost:4200/ask-question

Comment: whole code is same and I have nowhere defined localhost:4200/ask-question, All the routes of user is being rendered with and without user in the route-address.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on stackblitz?